# Return not so similar codes from a single group

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a list of product codes grouped in 2 or 3 lines. I need to return the group where codes are not same (or consecutive)

```
9003103
9003103

9003978
9003979

9003763
9003728

9003543
9003543
9003543
```

In this case, only the third group should be returned:

```
9003763
9003728
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
9003103
9003103

9003978
9003979

9003763
9003728

9003543
9003543
9003543
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{diff=$NF-$1;diff=diff>0?diff:-diff}diff>NF' file.txt
```

gives output

```
9003763
9003728
```

Explanation: I set `RS` to empty string to provoke paragraph mode, thus every block is treated as single line, then for each block I compute absolute of difference between first and last field, if difference is bigger than number of field block is printed.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: So you don't have to repeat `diff` so often, `diff=$NF-$1;diff=diff>0?diff:-diff` = `{diff=($NF>$1 ? $NF-$1 : $1-$NF)` or even `diff=sqrt(($NF-$1)^2)` so you could just write `awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}sqrt(($NF-$1)^2)>NF' file.txt` as long as the result of `$NF-$1` isn't huge. Obviously this approach would fail if the middle input from a set of 3 was the one that's different from the other 2, e.g. `9003978\n9004000\n003978`